# Get website resources

Tags: c#, networking, phantomjs, slimerjs

I have a task where I need to get a list of resources (and some basic information about them) for a given URL from .NET application.
With both Phantomjs and Slimerjs I was able to do this (`page.onResourceReceived` and `page.onResourceRequested`), however I'm looking if there is a better way (performance wise) to achieve the same from C#?

It's just that I'm not thrilled about the time it takes to execute that external process. Also seeing how I'm not using most of the functionalities of those scriptable browsers I was wondering if there was some other way to do this faster.

In other words, I don't need to do any DOM or CSS related manipulations. I just want to get the all the resources which are used by that page (let's say a much much simpler version of network panel of Chrome DevTools).